# How do I get these urls from JSON to load into my Xcode UICollection?

Tags: json, swift, api, uicollectionview

I have messed around with this API for such a long time now and I cannot figure out how to get the URLs to load into the UICollectionView that I have.
I am able to print just the URLs as seen in this image.
[image]

Also, here is what the JSON looks like when I print it.
[image]

And then here is my playground code that I am using to access the API.

```
let fortniteChallengesURL9 = URL(string: "https://api.fortnitetracker.com/v1/store")
    if let unwrappedURL = fortniteChallengesURL9 {
      var request = URLRequest(url: unwrappedURL) request.addValue("MY API KEY", forHTTPHeaderField: "TRN-Api-Key")

let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, err) in

    if let data = data {

        do {


            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
            print(json)
            print((json as AnyObject).value(forKey: "imageUrl")!)
           // print((json as AnyObject).value(forKey: "name")!)

            let urlImages = (json as AnyObject).value(forKey: "imageUrl")!





            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() ) {



            }


        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)

        }

    }



}
dataTask.resume()

}
```

And then here is the UICollectionView that I would like to put it into. However, I made a mess of this code trying to figure out how to go about doing this. The images currently inside the collection would have to be replaced with WebViews, I would assume.

```
var arrayOfImages = [UIImage]()
var arrayOfIds = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()





    let collectionViewLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    collectionViewLayout?.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
    collectionViewLayout?.invalidateLayout()

    arrayOfImages = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Sats"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "location"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "news"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "challengeBtn"),#imageLiteral(resourceName: "LTM")]
    arrayOfIds = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOfImages.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView
    imageView.image = arrayOfImages[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let name = arrayOfIds[indexPath.row]
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: name)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
}
```

If anyone has a link to a full tutorial on how to do this, then that would be great. If not then please help because I have no idea where to start for the collectionView and I’d like to only use swift and not use any third party workarounds. Also, I’d be replacing the image views with webViews I would think or would I just keep the imageViews.

Comment: use kingfisher see their doc: https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text using copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
struct Root:Decodable {  
   let imageUrl:String
}
```

---

```
var arrayOfImages = [Root]()

arrayOfImages = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Root].self,from:data)
```

---

Then inside `cellForRowAt` use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:arrayOfImages[indexPath.row].imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

---

Don't for get to reload the collection inside the callback

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
   self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: What exactly is SDWebImage? Is there another way of doing this by just using swift without sdwebimage

Comment: sdwebimage will download the image and cache it for you , so not download every scroll as you currently want to do , read it's features in the link